# When does a port become "open"?

Tags: ports

Question is in the title. I do not need a definition of a port or anything that relates to it, I just want to know when a port becomes "open". Thanks in advance. I know it sounds stupid, but the reason why I fail to interpret the "open" term is because open can mean semantically/context-dependent used, as well as unused, but both of these interpretations are no synonyms to the word "open".

Comment: The answer depends on the context you're using. Are you asking what it means when a program like `nmap` says that a port is open?

Comment: exactly - ive stumbled upon the term in the field of port scanning(penetration testing etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A port becomes open when some process (usually a server application) starts listening for connections on it. In a language like C, this involves calling `socket()` to create a network socket, `bind()` to specify the port that it should accept connections on, and then `listen()` to wait for incoming connections.